# How do i get the number of documents in an index in Marqo

Tags: python, marqo

i would like to know if there is a way to get the number of documents i have added to an index in [marqo](https://marqo.pages.dev/), i have been adding docmunts to two different index but right now i don't know how many documents i have added to each. i tried doing this:

```
import marqo

mq = marqo.Client(url='http://localhost:8882')

first_index = mq.index("first-index").search(
    q="any_query"
    limit=100
)

second_index = mq.index("second-index").search(
    q="any_query"
    limit=100
)

print(len(first_index['hits']))
print(len(second_index['hits']))
```

this works because i know that the number of documents i have added is not upto 100. i would like to know if there is a more efficient way of getting the number of documents

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `get_stats()` method for that eg;

```
first_index_stats = mq.index("first-index").get_stats()

second_index_stats = mq.index("second-index").get_stats()

print(first_index_stats)
print(second_index_stats)
```

output;

```
{'numberOfDocuments': the_number_of_documents_added}
{'numberOfDocuments': the_number_of_documents_added}
```